# Directing from registration form to online payment website

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to link a registration form to an online payment website and I was given code from the payment website similar to the one below in order to link the two pages together. I don't see how I would implement this unless it's attributed to an asp:Button like below.

How would I make it so on the button click it would run through this form and this information would be sent? All this information is necessary and if it isn't sent then I just get an error page from the payment server.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />


<form id="input_form" action="https://secure.checkout" method="post">
    <input name="LMID" type="hidden" value="000935" />
    <input name="unique_id" type="hidden" value="4567"/>
    <input name="sTotal" type="hidden" value="150.00"/>
    <input name="webTitle" type="hidden" value="2013 Conference" />
    <input name="Trans_Desc" type="hidden" value="Conference Registration" />
    <input name="contact_info" type="hidden" value="Contact web admin" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you need to manipulate the data before the information is passed to `https://secure.checkout`? If not you, you should be able to place a `<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>` inside the form tag to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
<form id="input_form" action="https://secure.checkout" method="post">
    <input name="LMID" type="hidden" value="000935" />
    <input name="unique_id" type="hidden" value="4567"/>
    <input name="sTotal" type="hidden" value="150.00"/>
    <input name="webTitle" type="hidden" value="2013 Conference" />
    <input name="Trans_Desc" type="hidden" value="Conference Registration" />
    <input name="contact_info" type="hidden" value="Contact web admin" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I already made a submit button <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" /> which takes the users input information and puts it into an access database. I'm still fairly new to asp.net so I'm not sure how I would throw the users inputted information using input type rather than asp controls and using code-behind in C#.

Comment: Ok, the form is not being submitted to the external server unless the submit button is within the form tag.  Your payment server might have an API you could use on the server side.  What payment server are you using?

Comment: the payment server is through ebusiness

Comment: I have the submit button within the form tag but doesn't want to work.